# Graphene-Python documentation on clients view

Tags: metadata, graphene-python

The [description property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw5Ug.png) on GraphQL's schema elements can be viewed by the client. For example, GraphQL shows the description value for a field object in the type-ahead dropdown that lists fields available inside a selection set. This same description appears on the [documentation section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmpy1.png). Can this type of metadata documentation be added through graphene-gae? My set up:

**models.py:**

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
    headline = ndb.StringProperty()
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Author')
    created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

import graphene
from graphene_gae import NdbObjectType
```

**Schema.py:**

```
class ArticleType(NdbObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    articles = graphene.List(ArticleType)

    @graphene.resolve_only_args
    def resolve_articles(self):
        return Article.query()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=QueryRoot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add descriptions like this:

```
headline = ndb.StringProperty(description='Add description here!')
```

Super Easy!